# Use CASE statement with VARCHAR column And SUM()

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I have a situation where the data type of the column is `VARCHAR(500)` and I am casting to `DECIMAL(16,2)` for a SUM() but I need to add a CASE statement/expression to alter to a *text string* if certain conditions are met.  I have tried the below syntax, but I get an error of

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 7
>   Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

I can not change DDL - so what change in this query needs to be made in order for the case statement to execute succesfully?

```
DECLARE @TestData Table (
        id int, 
        rep varchar(500), 
        amt varchar(500))

INSERT INTO @TestData (id, rep, amt) 
VALUES
(1, 'John', '200.00'), 
(2, 'John', '300.00'), 
(3, 'John', '10,00'),
(4, 'Gabe', '245.00'), 
(5, 'Gabe', NULL), 
(6, 'Gabe', '0.00')

SELECT id, John, Gabe
FROM (
        SELECT id, rep, TotalAmt = CASE WHEN id IN (1, 4, 6) THEN 'RC(1000)' 
        ELSE SUM(CAST(amt AS DECIMAL(16,2))) END FROM @TestData
        GROUP BY id, rep
     ) x
PIVOT ( SUM(x.TotalAmt) FOR rep IN ([John],[Gabe])) As SalesRep
```

Comment: Please add the output that you want. Right now you're doing a sum of a VARCHAR value and it isn't clear to me what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Why is the amount for id 3 using a comma and the others using a decimal point?

Comment: Why is the `GROUP BY` and `SUM()` there? `id` seems to be unique.

Comment: Could you filter out the IDs you want that specific value for in another query? You would be splitting the query in 2, but it might be cleaner to do that.

Comment: Your CASE results in a numeric column and thus tries to convert 'RC(1000)'  to a decimal.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a column that holds both `VARCHAR(500)` and `DECIMAL(16,2)`. The query initially gets a `DECIMAL(16,2)` value and thus sets the `TotalAmt` column in the subquery as a `DECIMAL(16,2)` column; when it generates a value a `'RC(1000)'`, it tries and fails to convert that to `DECIMAL(16,2)`.

You can make the subquery work by converting the results of the `SUM` to `VARCHAR`:

```
FROM (
      SELECT id, rep, TotalAmt = CASE WHEN id IN (1, 4, 6) THEN 'RC(1000)' 
      ELSE CAST(SUM(CAST(amt AS DECIMAL(16,2))) AS VARCHAR(20)) END FROM @TestData
      GROUP BY id, rep
     ) x
```

However, then your `SUM(x.TotalAmt)` in your `PIVOT` statement will fail. What should the results of the following be?

```
'RC(1000)' + 300.00 + 10.00
'RC(1000)' + 0.00 + 'RC(1000)'
```

It seems likely there's problem in the logic of what you're trying to do here, given the above.

NOTE: If `RC` is a function you're trying to call, you'll need to actually call the function instead of inserting the call into your data, or you'll have to use dynamic SQL to call it at some later time in your process.